# Can I use the values from CASE expressions in other CASE expressions?

Tags: postgresql, case

```
SELECT
  CASE -- result#1
     WHEN .. then 'a'
     WHEN .. then 'b'
  END,
  CASE -- result#2
     WHEN .. then 'c'
     WHEN .. then 'd'
  END, 
FROM table1
```

I have 2 CASE expressions above, can I use the result of both CASE expressions and create another CASE expression based on the values from both CASE expressions?

```
CASE
  WHEN result1 IS NOT NULL and result2 IS NOT NULL THEN '...'
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: Please include the real SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the result of a case expression at the same "block" that it is developed in. You need a sub select or a CTE.

```
select case  
          when result1 is not null
           and result2 is not null
          then '...'
          else null
       end "Final Result"
  from ( select case  
                   when .. then 'a'
                   when .. then 'b'
                   else null
                end result1 
                
             , case 
                   when .. then 'c'
                   when .. then 'd'
                   else null
               end result2
          from table1
       ) sq
```

OR

```
with first_case (result11, result22) as 
     ( select case    
                 when .. then 'a'
                 when .. then 'b'
                 else null
                end 
                
            , case 
                 when .. then 'c'
                 when .. then 'd'
                 else null
              end  
         from table1
      )
select case  
          when result1 is not null
           and result2 is not null
          then '...'
          else null
       end "Final Result"
  from first_case;
```